# integral defintion

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have a simple question about integral definition.
for example consider we want to compute the integral of $f(x)$ with respect to $t$ (time) in (a,b) in this situation we write :$\int_a^bf(x)dt$.

I think $dt$ means that we are computing the sum of very small rectangles.(the area of each rectangle is $f(x)dt$ ) (is it wrong?)

but I dont know what is the meaning of $\int_a^bdp(t)$ (p is another variable and again we want to take the integral of $p$ with respect to $t$ (time).(why there isn't any $dt$ in the end of the integral?)(for more details $p$ is linear momentum and $t$ is time)

Comment: Your question is unclear, particularly the last paragraph. $\int_a^b dp$ doesn't mean "take the integral of $p$ with respect to $t$." It means integral of $1$ with respect to $p$.

Comment: ∫badp∫abdp  doesn't mean "take the integral of p with respect to t." It means integral of 1 with respect to p. can you explain me this part of your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the notation is a shorthand for $$\int_a^b\frac{dp(t)}{dt}dt$$ This yields $p(b)-p(a)$.

Comment: so it is unnecessary to write $dt$ at the end of the integral?

Comment: You can "cancel" the dt terms. Just remember that $p$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: @jack.math. Instead of $dt$ you have $dp$. You can also see the [Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).